# Why does A=QR in this equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 a_1 & a_2 
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
q_1 & q_2
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_1^Tq_1 & a_2^Tq_1 \\ a_1^Tq_2 & a_2^T q_2 \end{bmatrix}
$$

In MIT's OCW 18.06 Prof Strang expresses A=QR factorization form as the equation above, but it really doesn't make sense to me, because if you dot product the right hand side out, you get:

$$\begin{bmatrix} q_1a_1^Tq_1  + q_2a_1^Tq_2 & q_1a_2^Tq_1 + q_2a_2^Tq_2
\end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: I'd add more context here. I believe in his notation that $A = QR$ is a factorization which is supposed to represent a Gram-Schmidt process in which $Q$ is upper triangular.

Comment: @JackPfaffinger $R$ is upper triangular

Comment: @egreg Oops, that was a typo, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbols $a_1,a_2,q_1,q_2$ stand for *column vectors*. The matrix on the left-hand side is $n\times 2$ and likewise $[q_1\quad q_2]$.

To the contrary, $a_i^Tq_j$ are scalars.

You can do block multiplication: the first column block is
$$
(a_1^Tq_1)q_1+(a_1^Tq_2)q_2=a_1
$$
because the column vectors $q_1,q_2$ are supposed to have norm $1$ and so they form an orthonormal basis of $\operatorname{span}\{a_1,a_2\}=\operatorname{span}\{q_1,q_2\}$. Then the result is just an application of the general theory.

Similarly for the second column.

*If* the orthonormal basis has been found using Gram-Schmidt, then we also know that $a_1^Tq_2=0$ (because $q_1$ is just the normalization of $a_1$ and $q_2$ is orthogonal to $q_1$, so also to $a_1$). Hence the $2\times2$ matrix is indeed upper triangular.